# ASP.NET strange Querystring

Tags: asp.net, session, query-string

I'm working on a older ASP.NET code which uses a SessionID string when navigating to the various pages:

```
/Myapp/Mypage.aspx?SessionID=08F7DCF3D6984EC984F6580A4EC7E9C2&PA=138883&FY=2014
```

This session ID is hard coded.

My understanding is sessionID is managed and preserved by the server.

To me this is a bad code but I may be wrong.

Can you think why this can be of any use.( Session ID magic number is not used later by pulling it from the querystring)

Comment: probably a stupid app that assumes no one has cookies enabled. Such code is major security risk. Imagine your bank using this system, and you cut/paste the url into an email. boom, the email recipient now has access to your bank accounts.

Comment: What is the role of cookies being enabled or not in this case? Yes to me also this a security issue.

Comment: session IDs are usually passed around via cookies, not passed in URLs, for exactly the reason in my other comment. A hard-coded session ID in the url means either the server is configured to not use cookies for sessions, or for some bizarre reason the developer is forcing everyone to share the same session.

Comment: Also don't confuse SessionID with relating to a standard ASP.Net Session object. Normally a Session in a URL that is generated by ASP.Net/IIS is appended as part of the URL and not as a querystring item. Try digging through the code to see what is looking for a querystring variable. It could very well be the application uses the same nomenclature but for a different purpose or using a custom mechanism to track users and data.

Comment: @SNash m, Check `web.config`, if that has `cookieless` = `true` , then for sure, you are using cookie less session, implies `session-id` will be there in URL - example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: I see `cookieless=`"false"`